Shortcut for computing $ \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1}{2x}\int_0^x \ln(t)t^2\,dt $
Suppose we want to find $$ \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1}{2x}\int_0^x \ln(t)t^2\,dt $$ without computing the integral. What I would do is this :
We know that $ 0 \leq t^2 \leq x^2$ for all $t \in (0,x)$
Then $ \ln(t)x^2 \leq \ln(t)t^2 \leq 0$ since $ \ln(t) \lt 0 ,x \in (0,1)$
By monotonicity of integration,
$$\begin{align*}
x^2\int_0^x\ln(t)\,dt &\leq  \int_0^x\ln(t)t^2\,dt \leq0\\
x^2(x\ln(x)-x) &\leq  \int_0^x\ln(t)t^2\,dt \leq0
\end{align*}
$$
When we take the limits at the extremes of the inequality,  both expressions are zero. By squeeze theorem, the original limit is zero.
I have certain doubts regarding this solution, especially because I am using monotonicity of integrals based in an inequality on an open Interval, with the integral on the left being improper.

Looks ok. You can also use L'Hopital's Rule.

Very simple approach. +1

The function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2\ln x & x>0\\ 0 &x=0\end{cases}$$ is continuous. Let $F$ denote the antiderivative of $f.$ Then $${1\over 2x}\int\limits_0^x f(t)\,dx={1\over 2}{F(x)-F(0)\over x}\\ \underset{x\to 0^+}{\longrightarrow} {1\over 2}F_+'(0)={1\over 2}f(0)=0$$
Remark In order to show continuity at $0$ it suffices to prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\ln x=0.$ It is possible to avoid l'Hopital rule. Indeed by substitution $x=e^{-t}$ we need to show $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to \infty}{t\over e^t}=0.$ If $n\le t<n+1$ then since $e>2$ we get  $${t\over e^t}\le {n+1\over e^n}\le {n+1\over 2^n} \le {n+1\over {n\choose 2}}\\ ={2(n+1)\over n(n-1)}\le {2(t+1)\over (t-1)(t-2)}\underset{t\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$ Alternatively we can use $(n+1)/e^n\to  0$ by the ratio test.

This means that my way of solving it is incorrect? Or you are just providing another solution?

No.  It means that there is a more general scheme that can be applied. So it is another solution.

To use L'Hopital's Rule instead of Squeeze Theorem, we note that the $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\int_0^xln(t)t^2dt}{2x}$ is of the indeterminate form $\frac00$, and thus the rule applies.
The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus gives us that $\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^xln(t)t^2dt=ln(x)x^2$
So our new limit becomes $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac12x^2ln(x)$
This can be rewritten as the following
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{ln(x)}{\frac{2}{x^2}}$$
This now is of the indeterminant form $\frac\infty\infty$, and so L'Hopital's rule applies again. From there, it's just a matter of simplifying the fraction and then directly substituting the value of $x=0$ into the expression.
